# Distance Traveled loop help Java

Tags: java, for-loop

I've been racking my brain trying to figure out why my program isn't looping right. Rather than getting each hour increments I'm only getting the final hour/speed. So if I put that I'm going 40 mph for 3 hours I only get 120.

Here is the problem:

The distance a vehicle travels can be calculated as follows:
Distance = Speed * Time
For example, if a train travels 40 miles-per-hour for three hours, the distance traveled is 120 miles. Write a program that asks for the speed of a vehicle (in mph) and the number of hours it has traveled. It should use a loop to display the distance a vehicle has traveled for each hour of a time period specified by the user. For example, if a vehicle is traveling at 40 mph for a three-hour time period, it should display a report similar to the one that follows:
Hour Distance Traveled

1 40

2 80

3 120

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Distance{
  public static void main(String [] args){
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

  int time , speed ,  hour;
  double  distance;

  System.out.println("How fast were you going ?");
  speed = keyboard.nextInt();

  while(speed<=0)
  {
     System.out.println("Please enter a valid speed ");
     speed = keyboard.nextInt();
  }

  System.out.println(" How long did you ride / drive ?");
  time = keyboard.nextInt();

  while(time<=0)
  {
     System.out.println("Please enter a valid time ");
     time = keyboard.nextInt();
  }

  System.out.println(" Hour                         Distance");
  System.out.println("---------------------------------");
  hour = 0;


  for( int x = 1; x<=time; x++)
  {
     hour++;
     if(hour>1)
     {
        distance = time * speed;
        System.out.println(time+ "                " +distance);
     }
    }
   }
  }
```

Comment: `distance = hour * speed;` instead of `distance = time * speed;`

Comment: Also, in your for loop, you can just use `x` instead of `hour`.  If it helps, you can get rid of all instances of `hour` first, and just rename `hour` to `x`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the variables `hour` and `distance`.

Change the name of the loop variable from `x` to `hour`.

Simply your loop to:

```
for( int hour = 1; hour <= time; hour++)
    System.out.println(hour+ " " + (hour * speed));
```

---

Note that if you did used your `distance` variable, it was a `double` which is the wrong type, because:

- both speed and time are `int`, so distance must be `int`
- the output of a `double` has a decimal point, but your requirements did not show one

Comment: Thanks for the help. And also thanks for pointing out my other mistakes, been beating myself up trying to figure this out all day!

Comment: No worries. Almost always, less code is good (as long as it's readable). Less code is easier to read and debug.

Answer (score 0):

use hour inside your loop instead of time,

```
 for( int x = 1; x<=time; x++) {
     hour++;
     if(hour>1) {
         distance = hour * speed;
         System.out.println(hour+ "                " +distance);
     }
 }
```

or just use x

Comment: Thanks for the help, it started at 80 which is fine I was able to fix it!